# Установка кода в модуль и на каждую страницу

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

У меня кнопки "Поделится" устанавливаются в модуль и он работает для каждой страницы отдельно. Получается что если я хочу на всех страницах установить социальные кнопки мне надо создать большое количество скриптов, для каждой страницы отдельно?

Comment: Ответ будет зависеть от технологии, применяемой при разработке сайта. Пожалуйста, укажите CMS, или фреймворк, который вы используете.